# React routes not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I think i got a problem using a very basic react router implementation.
When i load my *"localhost:8080/dist/"*, it WORKS, load the header component that is being imported on App, and load the IndexRoute properly, but when i try to access *"localhost:8080/dist/FPDV0200"* or *"localhost:8080/dist/FPDV0400"* it dosnt work. Any clues?

**app.component.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Header from '../header/header.component';

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <Header />
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**app.component.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, hashHistory, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from '../components/structure/app/app.component';
import Home from '../pages/home/home';
import FPDV0200 from '../pages/FPDV0200/FPDV0200';
import FPDV0400 from '../pages/FPDV0400/FPDV0400';

const routes = (
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="FPDV0200" component={FPDV0200}/>
        <Route path="FPDV0400" component={FPDV0400}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
);

export default routes;
```

Comment: Did you make sure your server gives you index.html no matter what path you request? Without the hash, you need the server to support it. Try with hash if you don't wanna do anything with the server.

Comment: try to add some <Link components inside of your home page. Click on this component and compare browser url with your expected urls.

Comment: I'm using browser-sync as a server for local development, i did a research now and find that i need to specify the 'connect-history-api-fallback' in the browser-sync options but it still wont work... i am server in localhost and using /dist because my dependencies files are in root... @goldbullet

Comment: Actualy i found the solution here: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204
and using the doc references from here https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Answer (score 1):

`localhost:8080/dist/FPDV0200` - this url should work in case of usage browserHistory.

You use hashHistory, so your url should look like this

```
localhost:8080/dist#FPDV0200
```

Comment: The second one using # really work but the browserHistory dosnt, i am using browser-sync to serve the application, read some stuff tryed to apply 'connect-history-api-fallback' but still wont work as expected...

Comment: Actualy i found the solution here: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204
and using the doc references from here https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback